# JavaScript never enters else block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why I can't get the code to enter the else block in this code:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();

if(n >= 6 || n <= 21) {
    $('body').html('<div id="bg"><img src="bg_day.jpg" alt=""></div>');
} else {
    $('body').html('<div id="bg"><img src="bg_night.jpg" alt=""></div>');
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `n >= 6 || n <= 21` is always true try  `n >= 6 && n <= 21`

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot get it working? Are you saying that the else condition is never invoked? Or are you saying that it does not work when it is invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add && and delete ||

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();

if(n >= 6 && n <= 21){
    $('body').html('<div id="bg"><img src="bg_day.jpg" alt=""></div>');
}
else{
    $('body').html('<div id="bg"><img src="bg_night.jpg" alt=""></div>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
f(n >= 6 || n <= 21){
```

should be

```
f(n >= 6 && n <= 21){
```

22 is greater than 6 so it will evaluate as true

Answer (score 4):

Rethink your logic. Every number is >= 6 or <= 21 so it will always be true. I think and (`&&`) is what you're looking for.

Comment: "*Every number is >= 6 or <= 21*". Except `NaN` :)

Comment: @Oriol A bit of an oxymoron, but correct!

Answer (score 4):

Your condition, `n >= 6 || n <= 21`, will be true for all numbers. `||` is the logical OR operator, for boolean values, it will return true if any either the condition on the left or the condition on the right is true<sup>1</sup>. Any number that is not greater than or equal to 6 will be less than or equal to 21.

I think you meant to use `&&`:

```
if(n >= 6 && n <= 21){
    ...
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

<sup>1. It's actually a bit more complicated than that, due to short-circuiting and type conversion, but see the link above for more details.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

|| means OR: a number is always greater than 6 OR lower than 21, so your else branch will never be reached. What you need is &&